# Savedstateviewmodelfactory is finall, cannot inherit

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack, android-viewmodel

```
class SettingsViewModelFactory(application: Application, owner: SavedStateRegistryOwner) : SavedStateViewModelFactory(application, owner){


    override fun <T : ViewModel?> create(modelClass: Class<T>): T {
        if (modelClass.isAssignableFrom(SettingsViewModel::class.java)){
            return SettingsViewModel() as T
        }
        throw IllegalArgumentException("Invalid ViewModel class")
    }

}
```

I get a red underline below SavedStateViewModelFactory saying that the type is final and cannot be inherited from. What do I do? The documentation is too vague.
Also what state do I put into the return?

Comment: What are you actually trying to do with your own factory? The default factory supports no-argument constructors already.

Comment: Its marked final means you cant extend it and have to use it as it is. More info here 
https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/lifecycle/SavedStateViewModelFactory?authuser=2

Comment: I'm just following what I learned in the codelabs. Am I not supposed to make my own factories?

Comment: What codelab are you following? No, you don't need your own factory if you're not doing anything with it - the default factory is there for a reason.

Comment: This one: https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/kotlin-android-training-view-model/index.html?index=..%2F..android-kotlin-fundamentals#7

I'm trying to save some data after I press the back button and after some research I thought SavedStateHandle would be my solution so I just tried to apply that to the factory codelab that I went through. (More detail: I have a settings fragment where a user can select a theme with some radio buttons and I want the radio button selection to be saved after the user navigates away from the fragment)

Comment: That codelab says nothing about extending `SavedStateViewModelFactory` and uses a custom factory because they pass the `finalScore` variable to their ViewModel...something your code doesn't do at all.

Comment: Yea I know. I'm mixing the codelab with this: https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/viewmodel-savedstate#kotlin

Comment: I mean, the docs there specifically use the default factory.

Comment: Oh so I don't even need SavedStateViewModel and I can just persist my radiobuttons the same way as in the codelab?

Comment: ViewModels and any data stored in them, be it via `SavedStateHandle` or not, still get destroyed when the user navigates away from the page. You'd want need to [persist your data to disk](https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/shared-preferences) if you want it to be saved forever.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you want to create your own factory that allows for usage of `SavedStateHandle` constructor parameters, you would extend [`AbstractSavedStateViewModelFactory`](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/lifecycle/AbstractSavedStateViewModelFactory), not `SavedStateViewModelFactory` as per the [explicit note on the documentation](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/viewmodel-savedstate):

> When providing a custom `ViewModelProvider.Factory` instance, you can enable usage of `SavedStateHandle` by extending `AbstractSavedStateViewModelFactory`.

However, you don't need any custom factory to support a ViewModel with a zero argument constructor - that is supported by default. You'd only need a custom factory if you need to pass custom parameters to your ViewModel. In your code's case, you can delete your custom factory entirely.

Comment: what if you're looking to support an AndroidViewModel with a few dependencies (other than the SavedStateHandle). AbstractSavedStateViewModelFactory doesn't seem to support AndroidViewModels. i guess the alternative is to hold the app context in your own viewmodel?

Comment: @takecare - it would be up to you to have your subclass of `AbstractSavedStateViewModelFactory` also take an `Application` object and pass that to an [`AndroidViewModelFactory`](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/lifecycle/ViewModelProvider.AndroidViewModelFactory) if you don't have a custom constructor for your `ViewModel` or otherwise need to pass an `Application` to your `ViewModel`.